# xmonad - switching workspaces with mouse buttons 6 and 7

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I would like to be able to move to the previous and next workspaces using the buttons 6 and 7 (the rocker buttons either side of the wheel) on my mouse.  I'm guessing it has something to do with `additionalMouseBindings`, and if that followed the same pattern as `additionalKeys` I'd be golden.  Alas, it is not, and I don't fully understand how to define a new binding.  The naive:

```
`additionalMouseBindings`
[ -- get the middle button to switch views
  ((0, button6), spawn "xdotool key super+Down")
, ((0, button7), spawn "xdotool key super+Up")
]
```

isn't working, for reasons that will be obvious to somebody who knows Haskell and xmonad.

TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: IIRC, the core X11 protocol has only five buttons. Other buttons can be detected using X extensions (XINPUT, maybe? I forgot), but I have no idea about whether xmonad exploits such extensions as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "doesn't work" I suppose you mean it doesn't compile.

After @chi comment, I checked the buttons : [button6 and 7 are not defined](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/X11/Graphics-X11-Types.html#t:Button), so that is a first problem. But according to [this post](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2010-July/010372.html) the extra buttons work if you just give their number.

It looks like you are using the [`additionalMouseBindings`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html#v:additionalMouseBindings) function from the XMonad.Util.EZConfig module. Its type is :

```
additionalMouseBindings :: XConfig a -> [((ButtonMask, Button), Window -> X ())] -> XConfig a
```

You are surrounding it in backticks which turns it into an operator. You aren't showing the first operand here, of type [`XConfig a`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#t:XConfig), so you could have a first error here. You should have something of the form :

```
 yourPreviousConfig `additionalMouseBindings` listOfBindings
```

That expression is equal to your new XConfig.

You can see that the list of bindings for the mouse buttons is not the same type as for the keys. The elements of the list are of type `((ButtonMask, Button),   Window -> X ())` : buttons are associated to a function that takes a `Window` and returns `X()` (whereas keys are associated to expressions of type `X()`). XMonad will call the function you specify here with the clicked window as argument. You don't care about the window in your case.   `spawn "xdotool key super+Down"` is of type `X ()`, you can turn that into a function that takes a `Window` (or anything) by making a [lambda function](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function) :

```
((0, 6), \w -> spawn "xdotool key super+Down")
```

Or you can use [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:const) to get a constant function that always return `spawn "xdotool key super+Down"` :

```
((0, 6), const $ spawn "xdotool key super+Down")
```

Finally, it seems really overkill to call `xdotool` to switch workspaces. Perhaps you are already using [some of the functions of the module here](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-CycleWS.html) in your key bindings ? You can use them in your mouse bindings too. `nextWS` and `prevWS` are of type `X()`, so you need make constant functions with them, like above.

Comment: It was indeed a compile error based on the absence of a window argument.  Your suggestions worked perfectly.  I settled on: `((0, 6), \w -> moveTo Prev (WSIs notSP))`  with an appropriate scratchpad filter defined.  Thanks for your help.